# Where can you find your community-wiki answers?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

Is it possible to find answers you posted as a community wiki answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the site search:

```
wiki:1 user:me is:a
```

are the commands you're seeking for. [Live example on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+user%3Ame+is%3Aa).

[More detailed help.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Worth noting that this search also catches the answers which were 1) automatically converted to because the question was CW 2) converted to CW by a mod.

Comment: @Sha Changing the example to SO since the search yields no results for OP there.

Comment: Correct, but worth to mention this will find answers being CW due to question being CW, not only answers the author marked explicitly as CW when posting, or while editing. (I think finding those is not possible.)

Comment: @Sha Yup, done.